# unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address arm

Tags: memory, kernel, paging, embedded-linux

My gstreamer program for dm368 which does streaming + DVI o/p + recording on demand always crashes with the error unable to handle kernel paging request at some virtual address. Can somebosy shed some light on how to debug the issue.

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 0c0c9ca0
pgd = c0004000
[0c0c9ca0] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/irqk/irqk/dev
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
CPU: 0    Not tainted  (2.6.32-17-ridgerun #22)
PC is at blk_rq_map_sg+0x70/0x2c0
LR is at mmc_queue_map_sg+0x2c/0xa4
pc : [<c01751ac>]    lr : [<c025a42c>]    psr: 80000013
sp : c23e1db0  ip : c3cf8848  fp : c23e1df4
r10: c3cf6258  r9 : 00001000  r8 : c23d2e40
r7 : 83c1e000  r6 : c3cf8880  r5 : 0c0c9c9c  r4 : c20f1400
r3 : 00000001  r2 : 00000c0d  r1 : 00000c0c  r0 : 00000000
Flags: Nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Control: 0005317f  Table: 818f4000  DAC: 00000017
Process mmcqd (pid: 978, stack limit = 0xc23e0270)
Stack: (0xc23e1db0 to 0xc23e2000)
1da0:                                     c20f1400 00000c0c 00005000 00000001
1dc0: 00000001 00000000 c23e1e14 c20e3604 c3cf6258 c23e0000 c21ae600 c3cf6258
1de0: c20e3604 00000001 c23e1e14 c23e1df8 c025a42c c017514c c23e1e94 c3cf6258
1e00: c23e0000 c21ae600 c23e1f9c c23e1e18 c0259cc8 c025a410 00000001 00000000
1e20: c23e1e3c 00000000 c23e1e3c c23e1e94 c23e1e68 00000000 00000000 00000019
1e40: 00037f36 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 000000b5 00000000 00000000
1e60: 00000000 00000000 0000000c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
1e80: 0000049d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11e1a300 00000000 00000200
1ea0: 00000080 00000000 00000100 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 c20f1400
1ec0: c20f1300 00000000 c23e1eec c23e1ed8 c016ec50 c01821bc c3cf6258 c20f1318
1ee0: c23e1f0c c23e1ef0 c016d5bc c016d43c c20f1300 c3cf6258 00000000 00000000
1f00: c23e1f34 c23e1f10 c017a154 c016d5a4 00000000 00000000 c20f1300 c3cf6258
1f20: 00000000 00000001 c23e1f5c c23e1f38 c017a6ac c017a058 c23e0000 c23d2e40
1f40: c23e0000 c23d2e40 c3cf6258 c23d2e40 c23e1f84 c23e1f60 c3cf6258 00000000
1f60: c23e1f84 c23e1f70 c016fa6c c0175594 c3cf6258 c23e0000 c3cf6258 c20e3604
1f80: c20e360c c23d2e40 00000000 c23d2fa0 c23e1fc4 c23e1fa0 c025a998 c0259b74
1fa0: c23e1fcc c207fd98 c20e3604 c025a884 00000000 00000000 c23e1ff4 c23e1fc8
1fc0: c0054a80 c025a894 00000000 00000000 c23e1fd0 c23e1fd0 00000000 00000000
1fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c23e1ff8 c0041520 c0054a08 625f746e 646e756f
Backtrace: 
[<c017513c>] (blk_rq_map_sg+0x0/0x2c0) from [<c025a42c>] (mmc_queue_map_sg+0x2c/0xa4)
[<c025a400>] (mmc_queue_map_sg+0x0/0xa4) from [<c0259cc8>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq+0x164/0x7cc)
 r7:c21ae600 r6:c23e0000 r5:c3cf6258 r4:c23e1e94
[<c0259b64>] (mmc_blk_issue_rq+0x0/0x7cc) from [<c025a998>] (mmc_queue_thread+0x114/0x118)
[<c025a884>] (mmc_queue_thread+0x0/0x118) from [<c0054a80>] (kthread+0x88/0x90)
[<c00549f8>] (kthread+0x0/0x90) from [<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c)
 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
Code: e0252593 e50b1030 ea000043 e51b3034 (e5959004) 
---[ end trace c3f2f2bb3920d771 ]---
time: 1770
time123: 1770
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address b6b8b8bc
pgd = c04d4000
[b6b8b8bc] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#2] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/irqk/irqk/dev
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
CPU: 0    Tainted: G      D     (2.6.32-17-ridgerun #22)
PC is at kmem_cache_alloc+0x38/0xa8
LR is at load_elf_binary+0x24/0x11c8
pc : [<c0098528>]    lr : [<c00da614>]    psr: a0000093
sp : c3831e38  ip : c3831e60  fp : c3831e5c
r10: 00000000  r9 : c2d28800  r8 : 00000000
r7 : 00000080  r6 : 000000d0  r5 : 60000013  r4 : b6b8b8bc
r3 : 00000000  r2 : 0000457f  r1 : 000000d0  r0 : c03f840c
Flags: NzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 0005317f  Table: 804d4000  DAC: 00000015
Process video_capture_a (pid: 1537, stack limit = 0xc3830270)
Stack: (0xc3831e38 to 0xc3832000)
1e20:                                                       c0087044 c007b2d4
1e40: c3830000 c04060cc c2d28800 00000001 c3831f0c c3831e60 c00da614 c0098500
1e60: 00000001 00000000 c1325780 c20b6000 c3831fb0 00000020 00000000 c20b6000
1e80: c3831ee4 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 41675d70 c3831ecc c3831ea8
1ea0: c0088304 c0087ff0 00000017 c3831ee4 00000000 c3831ec0 c3830000 c2d28800
1ec0: c3831f04 c3831ed0 c00a0fc4 c00882bc 00000001 00000001 c3831ee4 c3831e5c
1ee0: 00000000 c3830000 c04060cc c2d28800 00000001 00000000 c00da5f0 00000000
1f00: c3831f4c c3831f10 c00a1510 c00da600 c0503000 c3831fb0 c2d28802 fffffff8
1f20: c3831fb0 00000000 c2d28800 c3830000 00000001 beec1e7c c3831fb0 41675d70
1f40: c3831f84 c3831f50 c00a2944 c00a1400 4065b714 00000000 c00a64d0 c2015000
1f60: 41675d70 beec1e7c c3831fb0 c002b0e4 c3830000 00000e20 c3831fa4 c3831f88
1f80: c002df60 c00a27e4 40673e20 00000000 40673000 0000000b 00000000 c3831fa8
1fa0: c002af60 c002df34 40673e20 00000000 4065b714 41675d70 beec1e7c 00000164
1fc0: 40673e20 00000000 40673000 0000000b 41675c64 41675cf0 00000e20 0000cc60
1fe0: 41675c48 41675c58 40584940 405de30c 00000010 4065b714 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c00984f0>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0xa8) from [<c00da614>] (load_elf_binary+0x24/0x11c8)
 r7:00000001 r6:c2d28800 r5:c04060cc r4:c3830000
[<c00da5f0>] (load_elf_binary+0x0/0x11c8) from [<c00a1510>] (search_binary_handler+0x120/0x330)
[<c00a13f0>] (search_binary_handler+0x0/0x330) from [<c00a2944>] (do_execve+0x170/0x270)
[<c00a27d4>] (do_execve+0x0/0x270) from [<c002df60>] (sys_execve+0x3c/0x5c)
[<c002df24>] (sys_execve+0x0/0x5c) from [<c002af60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
 r7:0000000b r6:40673000 r5:00000000 r4:40673e20
Code: e5904080 e5907090 e3540000 1590308c (17943103) 
---[ end trace c3f2f2bb3920d772 ]---
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address b8cec4cd
pgd = c04d4000
[b8cec4cd] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 1 [#3] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/irqk/irqk/dev
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
CPU: 0    Tainted: G      D     (2.6.32-17-ridgerun #22)
PC is at unmap_vmas+0x5d0/0x634
LR is at free_hot_cold_page+0x1ec/0x24c
pc : [<c00893c4>]    lr : [<c0077de0>]    psr: a0000013
sp : c3831bb8  ip : 40e78000  fp : c3831c24
r10: c03faa70  r9 : 00000000  r8 : c3ab39dc
r7 : c3830000  r6 : b8cec4c9  r5 : eaa3a0a6  r4 : c0449fe0
r3 : ffffffff  r2 : c7d1d4f0  r1 : eaa3a0a6  r0 : 00000002
Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 0005317f  Table: 804d4000  DAC: 00000015
Process video_capture_a (pid: 1537, stack limit = 0xc3830270)
Stack: (0xc3831bb8 to 0xc3832000)
1ba0:                                                       ffffffff 00000000
1bc0: c3831c34 00000001 00007fff 00000000 40e78000 c04d5038 804ff3cf 00000000
1be0: 00000000 c1325600 00000000 40e78000 40e78000 c04d5038 00000001 c3830000
1c00: 00000000 c12dddc0 c1325600 00000005 00000001 c1325634 c3831c54 c3831c28
1c20: c008c0c0 c0088e04 c3831c30 00000000 000009bc c03faa70 c1325600 00000000
1c40: c1325600 c1325634 c3831c6c c3831c58 c003bb4c c008c00c c3830000 c20b6000
1c60: c3831c94 c3831c70 c003fc8c c003bb1c c20b6000 c3831df0 0000000b c20b6000
1c80: c3831df0 c0396040 c3831cac c3831c98 c00416bc c003fb4c c003de48 c003dcac
1ca0: c3831cc4 c3831cb0 c002ec0c c0041530 c3830270 00000005 c3831ce4 c3831cc8
1cc0: c00306b0 c002ea80 00010000 c20b6000 b6b8b8bc c1325600 c3831d1c c3831ce8
1ce0: c0030890 c0030654 00000000 c2d99f40 c049cfa0 c03fa5fc c3831e24 c3831df0
1d00: 00000005 b6b8b8bc 20000093 00000000 c3831d3c c3831d20 c0030954 c00306d0
1d20: c03fa5fc c3831e24 00000005 c3831df0 c3831dec c3831d40 c002a334 c0030940
1d40: 00000000 c04d4000 c20b6000 00000000 c12dddc0 0000c000 c3cf7830 00000000
1d60: c3831dd4 c3831d70 c0087680 c0086884 00000004 00000000 00000000 c04df8f0
1d80: 0000000c c04d4000 00000000 c1325600 00000030 c00309e4 c3831db4 c3831da8
1da0: c007b8a8 c007b640 c3831dc4 c12dddc0 00000200 c20b6000 c3831dd4 c3831dc8
1dc0: c00594c0 c0182ad0 c3831e0c ffffffff c3831e24 000000d0 00000080 00000000
1de0: c3831e5c c3831df0 c002ab0c c002a308 c03f840c 000000d0 0000457f 00000000
1e00: b6b8b8bc 60000013 000000d0 00000080 00000000 c2d28800 00000000 c3831e5c
1e20: c3831e60 c3831e38 c00da614 c0098528 a0000093 ffffffff c0087044 c007b2d4
1e40: c3830000 c04060cc c2d28800 00000001 c3831f0c c3831e60 c00da614 c0098500
1e60: 00000001 00000000 c1325780 c20b6000 c3831fb0 00000020 00000000 c20b6000
1e80: c3831ee4 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 41675d70 c3831ecc c3831ea8
1ea0: c0088304 c0087ff0 00000017 c3831ee4 00000000 c3831ec0 c3830000 c2d28800
1ec0: c3831f04 c3831ed0 c00a0fc4 c00882bc 00000001 00000001 c3831ee4 c3831e5c
1ee0: 00000000 c3830000 c04060cc c2d28800 00000001 00000000 c00da5f0 00000000
1f00: c3831f4c c3831f10 c00a1510 c00da600 c0503000 c3831fb0 c2d28802 fffffff8
1f20: c3831fb0 00000000 c2d28800 c3830000 00000001 beec1e7c c3831fb0 41675d70
1f40: c3831f84 c3831f50 c00a2944 c00a1400 4065b714 00000000 c00a64d0 c2015000
1f60: 41675d70 beec1e7c c3831fb0 c002b0e4 c3830000 00000e20 c3831fa4 c3831f88
1f80: c002df60 c00a27e4 40673e20 00000000 40673000 0000000b 00000000 c3831fa8
1fa0: c002af60 c002df34 40673e20 00000000 4065b714 41675d70 beec1e7c 00000164
1fc0: 40673e20 00000000 40673000 0000000b 41675c64 41675cf0 00000e20 0000cc60
1fe0: 41675c48 41675c58 40584940 405de30c 00000010 4065b714 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c0088df4>] (unmap_vmas+0x0/0x634) from [<c008c0c0>] (exit_mmap+0xc4/0x1f0)
[<c008bffc>] (exit_mmap+0x0/0x1f0) from [<c003bb4c>] (mmput+0x40/0xfc)
 r7:c1325634 r6:c1325600 r5:00000000 r4:c1325600
[<c003bb0c>] (mmput+0x0/0xfc) from [<c003fc8c>] (exit_mm+0x150/0x158)
 r5:c20b6000 r4:c3830000
[<c003fb3c>] (exit_mm+0x0/0x158) from [<c00416bc>] (do_exit+0x19c/0x67c)
 r7:c0396040 r6:c3831df0 r5:c20b6000 r4:0000000b
[<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c) from [<c002ec0c>] (die+0x19c/0x1c0)
[<c002ea70>] (die+0x0/0x1c0) from [<c00306b0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x6c/0x7c)
[<c0030644>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x7c) from [<c0030890>] (do_page_fault+0x1d0/0x1e8)
 r7:c1325600 r6:b6b8b8bc r5:c20b6000 r4:00010000
[<c00306c0>] (do_page_fault+0x0/0x1e8) from [<c0030954>] (do_translation_fault+0x24/0xa4)
[<c0030930>] (do_translation_fault+0x0/0xa4) from [<c002a334>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0x9c)
 r7:c3831df0 r6:00000005 r5:c3831e24 r4:c03fa5fc
[<c002a2f8>] (do_DataAbort+0x0/0x9c) from [<c002ab0c>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
Exception stack(0xc3831df0 to 0xc3831e38)
1de0:                                     c03f840c 000000d0 0000457f 00000000
1e00: b6b8b8bc 60000013 000000d0 00000080 00000000 c2d28800 00000000 c3831e5c
1e20: c3831e60 c3831e38 c00da614 c0098528 a0000093 ffffffff
 r8:00000000 r7:00000080 r6:000000d0 r5:c3831e24 r4:ffffffff
[<c00984f0>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0xa8) from [<c00da614>] (load_elf_binary+0x24/0x11c8)
 r7:00000001 r6:c2d28800 r5:c04060cc r4:c3830000
[<c00da5f0>] (load_elf_binary+0x0/0x11c8) from [<c00a1510>] (search_binary_handler+0x120/0x330)
[<c00a13f0>] (search_binary_handler+0x0/0x330) from [<c00a2944>] (do_execve+0x170/0x270)
[<c00a27d4>] (do_execve+0x0/0x270) from [<c002df60>] (sys_execve+0x3c/0x5c)
[<c002df24>] (sys_execve+0x0/0x5c) from [<c002af60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
 r7:0000000b r6:40673000 r5:00000000 r4:40673e20
Code: 1afffebd e596600c e3560000 0a000003 (e5961004) 
---[ end trace c3f2f2bb3920d773 ]---
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
BUG: scheduling while atomic: video_capture_a/1537/0x00000002
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
Backtrace: 
[<c002e6a0>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x114) from [<c0304928>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r7:c3830000 r6:c20b6000 r5:c20b6000 r4:00000000
[<c0304910>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c0037acc>] (__schedule_bug+0x54/0x60)
[<c0037a78>] (__schedule_bug+0x0/0x60) from [<c0304c34>] (schedule+0x84/0x390)
 r5:c20b6000 r4:0000000b
[<c0304bb0>] (schedule+0x0/0x390) from [<c00415ec>] (do_exit+0xcc/0x67c)
[<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c) from [<c002ec0c>] (die+0x19c/0x1c0)
[<c002ea70>] (die+0x0/0x1c0) from [<c00306b0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x6c/0x7c)
[<c0030644>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x7c) from [<c003090c>] (do_bad_area+0x64/0x70)
 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:00000004 r4:e5961004
[<c00308a8>] (do_bad_area+0x0/0x70) from [<c00325e0>] (do_alignment+0x5ac/0x700)
[<c0032034>] (do_alignment+0x0/0x700) from [<c002a334>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0x9c)
[<c002a2f8>] (do_DataAbort+0x0/0x9c) from [<c002ab0c>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
Exception stack(0xc3831b70 to 0xc3831bb8)
1b60:                                     00000002 eaa3a0a6 c7d1d4f0 ffffffff
1b80: c0449fe0 eaa3a0a6 b8cec4c9 c3830000 c3ab39dc 00000000 c03faa70 c3831c24
1ba0: 40e78000 c3831bb8 c0077de0 c00893c4 a0000013 ffffffff
 r8:c3ab39dc r7:c3830000 r6:b8cec4c9 r5:c3831ba4 r4:ffffffff
[<c0088df4>] (unmap_vmas+0x0/0x634) from [<c008c0c0>] (exit_mmap+0xc4/0x1f0)
[<c008bffc>] (exit_mmap+0x0/0x1f0) from [<c003bb4c>] (mmput+0x40/0xfc)
 r7:c1325634 r6:c1325600 r5:00000000 r4:c1325600
[<c003bb0c>] (mmput+0x0/0xfc) from [<c003fc8c>] (exit_mm+0x150/0x158)
 r5:c20b6000 r4:c3830000
[<c003fb3c>] (exit_mm+0x0/0x158) from [<c00416bc>] (do_exit+0x19c/0x67c)
 r7:c0396040 r6:c3831df0 r5:c20b6000 r4:0000000b
[<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c) from [<c002ec0c>] (die+0x19c/0x1c0)
[<c002ea70>] (die+0x0/0x1c0) from [<c00306b0>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x6c/0x7c)
[<c0030644>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x7c) from [<c0030890>] (do_page_fault+0x1d0/0x1e8)
 r7:c1325600 r6:b6b8b8bc r5:c20b6000 r4:00010000
[<c00306c0>] (do_page_fault+0x0/0x1e8) from [<c0030954>] (do_translation_fault+0x24/0xa4)
[<c0030930>] (do_translation_fault+0x0/0xa4) from [<c002a334>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0x9c)
 r7:c3831df0 r6:00000005 r5:c3831e24 r4:c03fa5fc
[<c002a2f8>] (do_DataAbort+0x0/0x9c) from [<c002ab0c>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
Exception stack(0xc3831df0 to 0xc3831e38)
1de0:                                     c03f840c 000000d0 0000457f 00000000
1e00: b6b8b8bc 60000013 000000d0 00000080 00000000 c2d28800 00000000 c3831e5c
1e20: c3831e60 c3831e38 c00da614 c0098528 a0000093 ffffffff
 r8:00000000 r7:00000080 r6:000000d0 r5:c3831e24 r4:ffffffff
[<c00984f0>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0xa8) from [<c00da614>] (load_elf_binary+0x24/0x11c8)
 r7:00000001 r6:c2d28800 r5:c04060cc r4:c3830000
[<c00da5f0>] (load_elf_binary+0x0/0x11c8) from [<c00a1510>] (search_binary_handler+0x120/0x330)
[<c00a13f0>] (search_binary_handler+0x0/0x330) from [<c00a2944>] (do_execve+0x170/0x270)
[<c00a27d4>] (do_execve+0x0/0x270) from [<c002df60>] (sys_execve+0x3c/0x5c)
[<c002df24>] (sys_execve+0x0/0x5c) from [<c002af60>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
 r7:0000000b r6:40673000 r5:00000000 r4:40673e20
^C^C^CUnable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address b6b8b8bc
pgd = c0004000
[b6b8b8bc] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#4] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/irqk/irqk/dev
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
CPU: 0    Tainted: G      D     (2.6.32-17-ridgerun #22)
PC is at kmem_cache_alloc+0x38/0xa8
LR is at mempool_alloc_slab+0x1c/0x20
pc : [<c0098528>]    lr : [<c0074944>]    psr: a0000093
sp : c2675d80  ip : c2675da8  fp : c2675da4
r10: c2675e9c  r9 : c2073578  r8 : 00011210
r7 : 00000080  r6 : 00011200  r5 : 00000013  r4 : b6b8b8bc
r3 : 00000000  r2 : c2675db8  r1 : 00011200  r0 : c03f840c
Flags: NzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Control: 0005317f  Table: 818f4000  DAC: 00000017
Process kjournald (pid: 984, stack limit = 0xc2674270)
Stack: (0xc2675d80 to 0xc2676000)
5d80: c2675dac c2675d90 00000001 c2674000 00000010 c2073560 c2675db4 c2675da8
5da0: c0074944 c0098500 c2675dfc c2675db8 c0074ab4 c0074938 c201c1a0 c201c1a0
5dc0: 00000000 00010259 c0405db8 c21fed80 c2675e24 00000001 00000000 00000010
5de0: 00000000 c2073520 00000001 c2675e9c c2675e2c c2675e00 c00c5c5c c0074a88
5e00: c20fb000 0000000f c20fb000 c21fed80 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001
5e20: c2675e3c c2675e30 c00c5d64 c00c5c3c c2675e64 c2675e40 c00c0434 c00c5d5c
5e40: c21fed80 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000001 00000001 c2675e94 c2675e68
5e60: c00c2688 c00c0378 0003002b 00000001 c210b7f8 00000014 c20fb000 00000100
5e80: c25d2000 c28252c0 c2675eb4 c2675e98 c0103d08 c00c2564 c00feb64 c21fed80
5ea0: c25d2020 c28252c0 c2675ef4 c2675eb8 c0103e80 c0103c5c c20fb058 00000001
5ec0: c2bf8f00 c210b7f8 c2675ef4 c2674000 c2674000 00000000 c20fb058 c2bf8f00
5ee0: 00000000 c20fb000 c2675f7c c2675ef8 c0101818 c0103d24 c20b6000 000006ed
5f00: 0003a773 c20fb094 c005a274 c21c8000 00000000 c20b6030 00000001 c21c8000
5f20: 0003a773 000006ed c005a2c0 c005a250 00000000 c0021780 c2675f7c c2675f48
5f40: c0304eb8 c0037ae8 c20b7658 c20b777c c2675f7c c2675f90 c2674000 c20fb000
5f60: c20b75e0 c20fb040 c20fb050 c20fb0c4 c2675fc4 c2675f80 c0105bdc c0100ef8
5f80: c2675fc4 00000000 c20b75e0 c0054ce8 c2675f90 c2675f90 c2675fc4 c2675fcc
5fa0: c2029ca8 c20fb000 c0105b08 00000000 00000000 00000000 c2675ff4 c2675fc8
5fc0: c0054a80 c0105b18 00000000 00000000 c2675fd0 c2675fd0 00000000 00000000
5fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c2675ff8 c0041520 c0054a08 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c00984f0>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0xa8) from [<c0074944>] (mempool_alloc_slab+0x1c/0x20)
 r7:c2073560 r6:00000010 r5:c2674000 r4:00000001
[<c0074928>] (mempool_alloc_slab+0x0/0x20) from [<c0074ab4>] (mempool_alloc+0x3c/0x158)
[<c0074a78>] (mempool_alloc+0x0/0x158) from [<c00c5c5c>] (bio_alloc_bioset+0x30/0xd4)
[<c00c5c2c>] (bio_alloc_bioset+0x0/0xd4) from [<c00c5d64>] (bio_alloc+0x18/0x30)
 r8:00000001 r7:00000000 r6:00000001 r5:00000000 r4:c21fed80
[<c00c5d4c>] (bio_alloc+0x0/0x30) from [<c00c0434>] (submit_bh+0xcc/0x194)
[<c00c0368>] (submit_bh+0x0/0x194) from [<c00c2688>] (ll_rw_block+0x134/0x1a0)
 r9:00000001 r8:00000001 r7:00000000 r6:00000003 r5:00000000
r4:c21fed80
[<c00c2554>] (ll_rw_block+0x0/0x1a0) from [<c0103d08>] (flush_descriptor+0xbc/0xc8)
[<c0103c4c>] (flush_descriptor+0x0/0xc8) from [<c0103e80>] (journal_write_revoke_records+0x16c/0x184)
 r4:c28252c0
[<c0103d14>] (journal_write_revoke_records+0x0/0x184) from [<c0101818>] (journal_commit_transaction+0x930/0x14e4)
[<c0100ee8>] (journal_commit_transaction+0x0/0x14e4) from [<c0105bdc>] (kjournald+0xd4/0x28c)
[<c0105b08>] (kjournald+0x0/0x28c) from [<c0054a80>] (kthread+0x88/0x90)
[<c00549f8>] (kthread+0x0/0x90) from [<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c)
 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
Code: e5904080 e5907090 e3540000 1590308c (17943103) 
---[ end trace c3f2f2bb3920d774 ]---
Recvd 2
in 2
^C^C^C^C^C^CUnable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address b6b8b8bc
pgd = c0004000
[b6b8b8bc] *pgd=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 5 [#5] PREEMPT
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/virtual/irqk/irqk/dev
Modules linked in: cmemk dm365mmap edmak irqk
CPU: 0    Tainted: G      D     (2.6.32-17-ridgerun #22)
PC is at kmem_cache_alloc+0x38/0xa8
LR is at mempool_alloc_slab+0x1c/0x20
pc : [<c0098528>]    lr : [<c0074944>]    psr: a0000093
sp : c2e5dbe8  ip : c2e5dc10  fp : c2e5dc0c
r10: c201c208  r9 : c2073578  r8 : 00011210
r7 : 00000080  r6 : 00011200  r5 : 00000013  r4 : b6b8b8bc
r3 : 00000000  r2 : c2e5dc20  r1 : 00011200  r0 : c03f840c
Flags: NzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment kernel
Control: 0005317f  Table: 818f4000  DAC: 00000017
Process flush-179:0 (pid: 1120, stack limit = 0xc2e5c270)
Stack: (0xc2e5dbe8 to 0xc2e5e000)
dbe0:                   c2e5dc4c c2e5dbf8 00000001 c2e5c000 00000010 c2073560
dc00: c2e5dc1c c2e5dc10 c0074944 c0098500 c2e5dc64 c2e5dc20 c0074ab4 c0074938
dc20: 00000000 c13a6708 00000000 00000001 c2114940 00000000 c21146f0 00000001
dc40: c0469c20 00000010 00000000 c2073520 c00c2090 c201c208 c2e5dc94 c2e5dc68
dc60: c00c5c5c c0074a88 c0180c20 0000000f c2e5c000 c3367b88 c0469c20 00000001
dc80: 00000000 c3367b88 c2e5dca4 c2e5dc98 c00c5d64 c00c5c3c c2e5dccc c2e5dca8
dca0: c00c0434 c00c5d5c 00000001 c0469c20 c3367b88 00000000 c3367b88 c00c2090
dcc0: c2e5dd1c c2e5dcd0 c00c3e9c c00c0378 c2114940 0003ffff 00000000 0003ccaf
dce0: c2e5ded8 c00c6c30 00001000 00000001 c0181834 3ccaf800 c0469c20 c201c208
dd00: 00000000 c00c6c30 c00c2090 c2e5ded8 c2e5dd54 c2e5dd20 c00c4150 c00c3b6c
dd20: c00c2090 c2e5dd30 c0071df4 c201c2a4 c2e5ded8 00000000 00000000 000003ff
dd40: 00000001 ffffffff c2e5dd64 c2e5dd58 c00c4170 c00c4040 c2e5dd74 c2e5dd68
dd60: c00c7d10 c00c416c c2e5dd8c c2e5dd78 c0078cb8 c00c7d08 c0469c20 c2e5ded8
dd80: c2e5de34 c2e5dd90 c007971c c0078cac 0000000e 00000000 00000000 c201c2a4
dda0: c0078c9c c201c2a4 c23d2ee0 00000002 0000008d 00003e49 00000000 c2e5ddc8
ddc0: 00000000 00000002 00000000 c047b680 c0469c20 c048cb00 c047b620 c048cb20
dde0: c04a7f60 c048cca0 c04a7e80 c0465140 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
de00: 00000000 00003e49 00000000 c201c208 00000004 c201c208 00000000 c2e5ded8
de20: c23d2f68 c201c2a4 c2e5de44 c2e5de38 c007987c c00794e0 c2e5de54 c2e5de48
de40: c00798b8 c007985c c2e5de7c c2e5de58 c00ba440 c0079894 00000000 c2e5c000
de60: c201c208 c23d2f40 c2001640 c2e5ded8 c2e5ded4 c2e5de80 c00bb218 c00ba36c
de80: c2e5c000 c2e5df14 00000000 00000000 0002486e c23d2f60 c1cf8350 c201c210
dea0: c201c210 c2001600 00000015 c2e5c000 00000000 c23d2f68 00000000 00000000
dec0: c23d2f40 c2e5df48 c2e5df44 c2e5ded8 c00bb44c c00bae40 c23d2ee0 00000000
dee0: 00000000 c2e5df14 00000400 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
df00: 00000014 00000000 c20b0fa0 c042a240 0002486e 00023cb6 c23d2f40 c2e5df48
df20: 00000000 c23d2f40 000015da 00000000 00000000 c23d2f80 c2e5df84 c2e5df48
df40: c00bb7b0 c00bb300 000015da 00000000 00000000 00000003 c03fe048 000001f4
df60: c2e5c000 00023882 c23d2f40 00000000 00000000 00000000 c2e5dfa4 c2e5df88
df80: c00bb804 c00bb604 c2e5c000 c23d2ee0 c23d2f40 c008577c c2e5dfc4 c2e5dfa8
dfa0: c0085810 c00bb7e4 c2e5dfcc c20a5f18 c23d2f40 c008577c c2e5dff4 c2e5dfc8
dfc0: c0054a80 c008578c 00000000 00000000 c2e5dfd0 c2e5dfd0 00000000 00000000
dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c2e5dff8 c0041520 c0054a08 00000000 00000000
Backtrace: 
[<c00984f0>] (kmem_cache_alloc+0x0/0xa8) from [<c0074944>] (mempool_alloc_slab+0x1c/0x20)
 r7:c2073560 r6:00000010 r5:c2e5c000 r4:00000001
[<c0074928>] (mempool_alloc_slab+0x0/0x20) from [<c0074ab4>] (mempool_alloc+0x3c/0x158)
[<c0074a78>] (mempool_alloc+0x0/0x158) from [<c00c5c5c>] (bio_alloc_bioset+0x30/0xd4)
[<c00c5c2c>] (bio_alloc_bioset+0x0/0xd4) from [<c00c5d64>] (bio_alloc+0x18/0x30)
 r8:c3367b88 r7:00000000 r6:00000001 r5:c0469c20 r4:c3367b88
[<c00c5d4c>] (bio_alloc+0x0/0x30) from [<c00c0434>] (submit_bh+0xcc/0x194)
[<c00c0368>] (submit_bh+0x0/0x194) from [<c00c3e9c>] (__block_write_full_page+0x340/0x4d4)
 r9:c00c2090 r8:c3367b88 r7:00000000 r6:c3367b88 r5:c0469c20
r4:00000001
[<c00c3b5c>] (__block_write_full_page+0x0/0x4d4) from [<c00c4150>] (block_write_full_page_endio+0x120/0x12c)
[<c00c4030>] (block_write_full_page_endio+0x0/0x12c) from [<c00c4170>] (block_write_full_page+0x14/0x1c)
[<c00c415c>] (block_write_full_page+0x0/0x1c) from [<c00c7d10>] (blkdev_writepage+0x18/0x20)
[<c00c7cf8>] (blkdev_writepage+0x0/0x20) from [<c0078cb8>] (__writepage+0x1c/0x6c)
[<c0078c9c>] (__writepage+0x0/0x6c) from [<c007971c>] (write_cache_pages+0x24c/0x37c)
 r5:c2e5ded8 r4:c0469c20
[<c00794d0>] (write_cache_pages+0x0/0x37c) from [<c007987c>] (generic_writepages+0x30/0x38)
[<c007984c>] (generic_writepages+0x0/0x38) from [<c00798b8>] (do_writepages+0x34/0x40)
[<c0079884>] (do_writepages+0x0/0x40) from [<c00ba440>] (writeback_single_inode+0xe4/0x24c)
[<c00ba35c>] (writeback_single_inode+0x0/0x24c) from [<c00bb218>] (writeback_inodes_wb+0x3e8/0x4c0)
[<c00bae30>] (writeback_inodes_wb+0x0/0x4c0) from [<c00bb44c>] (wb_writeback+0x15c/0x1f0)
[<c00bb2f0>] (wb_writeback+0x0/0x1f0) from [<c00bb7b0>] (wb_do_writeback+0x1bc/0x1e0)
[<c00bb5f4>] (wb_do_writeback+0x0/0x1e0) from [<c00bb804>] (bdi_writeback_task+0x30/0xd4)
[<c00bb7d4>] (bdi_writeback_task+0x0/0xd4) from [<c0085810>] (bdi_start_fn+0x94/0x10c)
 r7:c008577c r6:c23d2f40 r5:c23d2ee0 r4:c2e5c000
[<c008577c>] (bdi_start_fn+0x0/0x10c) from [<c0054a80>] (kthread+0x88/0x90)
 r7:c008577c r6:c23d2f40 r5:c20a5f18 r4:c2e5dfcc
[<c00549f8>] (kthread+0x0/0x90) from [<c0041520>] (do_exit+0x0/0x67c)
 r7:00000000 r6:00000000 r5:00000000 r4:00000000
Code: e5904080 e5907090 e3540000 1590308c (17943103) 
---[ end trace c3f2f2bb3920d775 ]---
```